# Trying to get the name of restaurants near a location using the google Places API

Tags: swift

So Im working with the google Places API trying to get the names of restaurants near a location that a user inputs but I'm encountering some issues with parsing the JSON. I did the following in the attached image but am having some difficulties because whenever I try to print out the names nothing appears and I can't figure out why.

```
import UIKit

struct RestaurantStruct: Decodable{
    let name:String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

         let url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restraunts%20near%20728%20west%2028th%20street&key=MYKEY"
            let urlObj=URL(string:url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data,response,err) in

                do{
                    var restraunts=try JSONDecoder().decode([RestaurantStruct].self, from: data!)
                    for restraunt in restraunts{
                        print(restraunt.name)
                    }
                }catch{
                   print("We got an error")
                }
            }.resume()


    }


}
```

Comment: Your query has `query=restraunts`, that should be `query=restaurants` ?

Comment: I fixed that but nothing is still printing out

Comment: So what does `data` look like, does it have the info you want? Also have a look at what's in `response`.

Comment: How would you recommend I do that `print(data!)`?

Comment: Try `let dataString  = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!` and then `print(dataString)`

Comment: It printed out what is returned when I enter the url into the search bar, the json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203545/discussion-between-koen-and-kyle-van-housen).

Comment: Unrelated. But what is the benefit/downside of using the Google Places API vs installing the Google Places SDK into your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in chat, it turned out that your model and json do not match. You could try something like this (as described in https://medium.com/@bryanryczek/how-to-download-and-parse-a-google-place-json-response-in-swift-4-with-codable-7b7d12bce8ae):

```
struct Restaurant: Codable {
    let name: String
}

struct GooglePlacesResponse: Codable {

    let restaurants : [Restaurant]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case restaurants = "results"
    }
}
```

and then to decode:

```
//...
if let data = data {
   let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GooglePlacesResponse.self, from: data)
   let restaurants = response.restaurants
   //...
}
```